# Proof of determinant formula

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, determinant

I have just started to learn how to construct proofs. That is, I am not really good at it (yet). In this thread I will work through a problem from my Linear Algebra textbook. First i will give you my "solution" and then, hopefully, you can tell me where I went wrong. If my proof strategy for this case is wrong I would love to hear why it's wrong (if it is possible) since I think that is how I will become better :)

My textbook says an often good proof strategy of different determinant formulas is by Mathematical induction and I think it also works in this case, but as i said earlier, I am not too good at constructing proofs yet.

---

**Problem:**


Let $X, Y$ be column-vectors. Show that $det(I+XY^T)=1+Y^TX$, where the last product is interpreted as a number.

---

Ok so here is my **attempt** to solve the problem:

Proof strategy: Induction

**1. Base case:**

The statement is true when n=2, since:
$$I=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \end{array} \right), XY^T=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
x_1y_1 & x_1y_2 \\
x_2y_1 & x_2y_2 \end{array} \right)$$

and

$|I+XY^T|=\begin{vmatrix}
x_1y_1+1 & x_1y_2\\ x_2y_1 & x_2y_2+1
\end{vmatrix}$

When we expand the determinant, we get:

$(x_1y_1+1)(x_2y_2+1)-x_1y_2x_2y_1= 1+(x_1y_1x_2y_2+x_1y_1+x_2y_2-x_1y_2x_2y_1)=1+(x_1y_1+x_2y_2)=1+Y^TX$

**2. induction hypothesis:**

Suppose it's true for the value $n-1$ and now I want to prove it's true for n.

**3. The inductive step:**  
$det(I+XY^T)=x_1y_1+x_2y_2+...+x_{n-1}y_{n-1}+x_ny_n + 1$

And here is where i pretty much get stuck. I don't know where to go from here. It's kinda hard for me to grasp the idea behind mathematical induction. I don't really know what to do when I come to this step. What can I do to finish the proof? (well, if what I have done so far is correct, that is).

Comment: The formula should be $$
\det(I+XY^T)=x_1y_1+\cdots x_ny_n+1
$$ in the induction step.

Comment: Ah thank you for catching that, my bad :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "holes-digging" method might be interesting to prove this.

On one hand, dig a hole at the lower-left corner of $A$,
$$A := \begin{bmatrix}I & X \\
-Y^T & 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\
Y^T & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}I & X \\
0 & 1 + Y^TX\end{bmatrix}$$
Take determinants on both sides to have $\det(A) = \det(I)\det(I + Y^TX) = \det(1 + Y^TX)$.

On the other hand, dig a hole at the upper-right corner of $A$,
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}I & X \\
-Y^T & 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} I & X \\
0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}I + XY^T & 0 \\
-Y^T & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
Take determinants on both sides to have $\det(A) = \det(I + XY^T)\det(1) = \det(I + XY^T)$.
Therefore, $\det(1 + Y^TX) = \det(I + XY^T)$.

Comment: I think this was a really cool proof. But i have a few questions (which may sound stupid to you):  


1. How did you know how you should define matrix A?
2. What method/algorithm did you use to factorize the matrix to the right hand side? Or did you just see it?

Thanks :)

Comment: @Joel For a a little lengthy background, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement

Comment: The underlying idea is Gauss elimination, applying it in a block matrix scale. Since the quantities appeared in the conclusion can be viewed as two Schur complements, the form of $A$ follows.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will take a look at the wikipedia link :)

Answer (score 0):

Your base case is solid. I'd like to suggest that you take a different approach to constructing the proof. Doing this inductively is likely to be pretty messy. Break into cases:

1. $x = 0$ or $y = 0$. In this case, the theorem's pretty clear (I hope!).
2. $x \ne 0$. In this case, you can set $x_1 = x$ and extend this to a basis $$ x_1, \ldots x_n$$ where the $x_i$ are pairwise perpendicular. If you then express $x$ and $y$ in this basis, it's relatively easy to write out the proof. And expressing it in that basis means replacing $I + x^t y$ with $Q (I + x^t y) Q^{-1}$, where $Q$ is a change-of-basis matrix, so it doesn't change the determinant, etc.

Comment: I think if a problem of his is to prove this identity, then he's probably not far enough in the text to know about basis vectors, change of basis matrices, etc.

Comment: Hmm. I would think that bases would come long before determinants. A quick glance at three of my linear algebra texts show that all three follow this pattern. But you could well be right.

Comment: Bases is the next chapter ;). But I think it's good to see different approches to one problem. I will take a look at your answers and try to understand it and perhaps comes back later if something is unclear :)

Comment: Ah, well. Wrong again. :)  Glad to provide a peek ahead to motivate that whole "basis" thing.